# infoBox/valueBox from shinyDashboard in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a simple shiny-app with just a dropdown listing districts of Afghanistan and a leaflet map of the same. [image]

The shape file can be accessed at this [link](http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/shp/AFG_adm_shp.zip) - using AFG_adm2.shp from http://www.gadm.org/download

here's the app code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

afg <- readOGR(dsn = "data", layer ="AFG_adm2", verbose = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test App"),
  selectInput("yours", choices = c("",afg$NAME_2), label = "Select Country:"),
  leafletOutput("mymap")

)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(afg) %>% addTiles() %>%
      addPolylines(stroke=TRUE, color = "#00000", weight = 1) 
  })
  proxy <- leafletProxy("mymap")

  observe({
    if(input$yours!=""){
      #get the selected polygon and extract the label point 
      selected_polygon <- subset(afg,afg$NAME_2==input$yours)
      polygon_labelPt <- selected_polygon@polygons[[1]]@labpt

      #remove any previously highlighted polygon
      proxy %>% removeShape("highlighted_polygon")

      #center the view on the polygon 
      proxy %>% setView(lng=polygon_labelPt[1],lat=polygon_labelPt[2],zoom=7)

      #add a slightly thicker red polygon on top of the selected one
      proxy %>% addPolylines(stroke=TRUE, weight = 2,color="red",data=selected_polygon,layerId="highlighted_polygon")
    }
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want a `infoBox` or `valueBox` like widget from **shinyDashboard** to display some data(like district population) below the map based on user selection. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the `shinydashboard::infoBox` with your own function:

1. create function

```
myInfoBox <- function(title, value)
{
 div(
  div(class='myinfobox-title', title),
  div(class='myinfobox-value', value)
 )
}
```

2. use `uiOutput()` whenever you want to place it e.g. `uiOutput('idOfInfoBox')`
3. in `server` part use e.g. `output$idOfInfoBox <- renderUI(myInfoBox(title, value)`
4. add .css file in `www/` directory and add some properties for classes `myinfobox-title` and `myinfobox-value`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You need to change the structure of the program and need to add dashboard page in UI.

Here are some reference just have a look. you will get to know!!!

https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html

https://rdrr.io/cran/shinydashboard/man/valueBox.html

Comment: It can be .. some of the changes needed in your shiny app. for  example you need to load shinydashboard package. try above links

Comment: So you mean I should switch to shinydashboard?

Comment: its not exactly switch, you should add dashboard also. infoboxes and value boxes do come under shinydashboard package . so you should add.. click this link    https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/